# Orthonormal Projection Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

I am auditing an online course titled "Mathematics for Machine Learning: PCA". The associated book is available [here](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book_printed.pdf), (page 88 eqn 3.65).
The discussion is limited to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The author claims both in the course and in the book that the projection of vector $x$ onto the subspace $U$ with basis matrix $\mathbb{B}$:
$$\pi_u(x) = \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{B}^T\mathbb{B})^{-1}\mathbb{B}^Tx$$

can be simplified to
$$\pi_u(x) = \mathbb{B}\mathbb{B}^Tx$$

when $\mathbb{B}$ is an Orthonormal basis ($\mathbb{B}^T\mathbb{B} = \mathbb{I}$).

But, if that is the case, wouldn't $\mathbb{B}$ also annihilate $\mathbb{B}^T$ which would result in:
$$\pi_u(x) = x$$
What am I missing here?

Comment: No, $ e_1^T e_1 = 1$ is  invertible but $e_1 e_1^T$ is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason why is because $B$ is not a square matrix.  It appears that if $U$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace with the an orthonormal basis of $U$ arranged in the columns of $B$, then $B$ will be an $n\times k$ matrix, hence when computing $B^TB$ this will be an $k\times k$ identity matrix.  To illustrate this, imagine that $B = [u_1 \;\; u_2 \;\; \ldots \;\; u_k]$ where each $u_i$ is a column vector, then the computation

$$
B^TB \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
u_1^T \\\vdots \\ u_k^T \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
u_1 & \ldots & u_k \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
\langle u_1, u_1\rangle & \langle u_1, u_2 \rangle & \ldots & \langle u_1, u_k\rangle \\
\langle u_2, u_1\rangle & \langle u_2, u_2 \rangle & \ldots & \langle u_2, u_k\rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle u_k, u_1\rangle & \langle u_k, u_2 \rangle & \ldots & \langle u_k, u_k\rangle \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

which clearly reduces to the $k\times k$ identity matrix.  Notice that if we arrange the other product $BB^T$ we don't obtain the same form as we do above.